# SQL Query To Get All Records From One Table, Except A Specific Record, By Date, From Another Table

Tags: mysql, left-join, unions

I am trying to SELECT records from two MySql tables.  I would like all records from the first table excluding specific records, by date, from the second table.  For example:

**Table1** `T1id`, `firstName`, `LastName` 
**Table2** `id`, `T1id`, `hours`, `rate`, `date`

`T1id` is the link between the two tables, therefore when the tables are joined I would have `T1id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `hours`, `rate`, `date`

Let's say there is a record in **Table2** with a `date` of 2012-02-08.  With one query, I need to select all records from **Table1**, ***excluding the record from Table2 that has the date of 2012-02-08***.

I've tried a few variations of JOINS and UNIONS, however I either get all records, a bunch of duplicate records, or one record (i.e. Table2 date).  I apologize, but I do not have a specific piece of code to include since nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many times this is typically done with a NOT EXISTS subquery, but subqueries can be big performance hits in larger tables... However, by doing a LEFT JOIN and looking for NULL is in essence, the same result

```
select
      t1.*
   from
      table1 t1
         left join table2 t2
            on t1.t2.t1id
          AND t2.date = '2012-02-08'
   where
      t2.t1id IS NULL
```

Comment: I just used your suggestion in my query and viola, it worked.  I actually tried everything included in your suggestion separately, but did not think to put it all together (i.e. LEFT JOIN, AND date, and IS NULL)  - Thnx

Comment: @user175328, glad it worked... by having the "AND DATE" associated with the join qualifies at that specific level, not the entire "WHERE" clause... Neat trick I've learned quite a while back on the LEFT JOIN / NULL test... especially if working a table with mil records than sub-select for each row being tested.

Answer (score 1):

USE `INNER JOIN` if you are sure that T1id exists in both tables:

```
SELECT  a.T1id, 
        a.FirstName, 
        a.LastName, 
        b.hours, 
        b.rate, 
        b.date
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b
        ON a.T1id = b.T1id
WHERE b.date <> DATE('2012-02-08')
```

but if you want to get all `T1id` from Table1 *(which exists or does not exists in Table2*) use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.T1id, 
        a.FirstName, 
        a.LastName, 
        b.hours, 
        b.rate, 
        b.date
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
        ON a.T1id = b.T1id
WHERE b.date <> DATE('2012-02-08')
```

Comment: Thnx for the quick response.  Unfortunately, both suggestions resulted in all records within Table2 that do not have the date 2012-02-08.  I am trying to get all records from Table1, minus the Table2 2012-02-08 record.